# extract unique value from a log4j log file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

Im having trouble extracting only a matching string: OPER^ from a log4j file.
I can get this value from two different sources inside my log file:

```
2012-01-26 03:06:45,428 INFO  [NP_OSS] OSSBSSGWIMPL6000|**OPR20120126120537008893**|GenServiceDeactivationResponse :: processRequestGenServiceDeactivationResponse() ::
```

or:

```
2012-01-26 03:06:45,411 INFO  [NP_OSS] MESSAGE_DATA = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:ServiceDeactivationResponse xmlns:ns2="urn:ngn:foo"><MessageHeader><MessageTimeStamp>20120126031123</MessageTimeStamp>**<OperatorTrxID>OPR20120126120537008893</OperatorTrxID>**</MessageHeader></ns2:ServiceDeactivationResponse>
```

I need to extract only the value **OPR***
I'm guessing its much easier to extract it from the first one since it doesn't involve parsing xml.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo $line | grep OPR | sed -e "s/^.*OPR\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/"
```

**Edit:**

After reading your comment:

```
$ echo $line | grep OPR | sed -e "s/^.*\(OPR[0-9]*\).*$/\1/" | head -1
```

Comment: very close :) but that omits the OPR part (which i need) and gives me multiple results, i just need the first one :)

Answer (score 5):

maybe I didn't understand OP's question well, why a simple grep command cannot do the job?

like

```
grep -Po 'OPR\d+'
```

output for both lines are same:

```
OPR20120126120537008893
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk`: *Setting up Field Separators*

```
awk -v FS="[<>]" '{print $13}' logfile
```

`perl`: *Using Positive look ahead and look behind*

```
perl -pne 's/.*(?<=\<OperatorTrxID\>)([A-Z0-9]+)(?=\<\/OperatorTrxID\>).*/$1/' logfile
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat logfile
2012-01-26 03:06:45,411 INFO  [NP_OSS] MESSAGE_DATA = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:ServiceDeactivationResponse xmlns:ns2="urn:ngn:foo"><MessageHeader><MessageTimeStamp>20120126031123</MessageTimeStamp><OperatorTrxID>OPR20120126120537008893</OperatorTrxID></MessageHeader></ns2:ServiceDeactivationResponse>

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v FS="[<>]" '{print $13}' logfile
OPR20120126120537008893

[jaypal:~/Temp] perl -pne 's/.*(?<=\<OperatorTrxID\>)([A-Z0-9]+)(?=\<\/OperatorTrxID\>).*/$1/' logfile
OPR20120126120537008893
```